# Sugarcrm logging

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have an installation of sugarcrm and my logs have debug entries even if the logging level is set to fatal.
What causes the logger to ignore the settings? I searched for code that overrides the logging level but didn't find anything like that.

Seems to be a problem that is only occuring on REST api calls.

Comment: hi im also having problem about sugarcrm, my username and password won't connect dunno why. Im using this library https://github.com/asakusuma/SugarCRM-REST-API-Wrapper-Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the SugarCRM Version. I used 5.5.4 for this and there is *$GLOBALS['log']->setLevel('debug');* in line 44 of service/core/webservice.php.

at least since version 6.2 it's gone .-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there isn't a conflicting log setting getting in the way here, perhaps in the config.php, or config_override.php file?

Comment: in both I have $sugar_config['logger']['level'] = 'fatal';

Comment: ahh I should add that I use a custom api

Comment: any ideas? I can't find the reason for it. How can I narrow down the problem?

Comment: Have you done any customizations to the instance? I'm thinking there is code somewhere forcing it to write those entries.

Comment: not that I know. I'm searching again for anything that may changes the log level.

Comment: I didn't find anything. Maybe an error because of my customisation to the API causes that. At the moment I have no time to search further because it isn't really problematic. As soon as I find something I'll get back.

Comment: unfortunately the problem isn't gone and I don't find any hint on code that could cause this.